# Zombie crash because of Swift inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I have Swift class (derived of `UIView`), which I call in Objective C++ code.

Initially, it worked well and looked like this:

```
@objc
public class HorizonView: UIView {

    var dashGap: (CGFloat, CGFloat)? = nil

    let titleLayer = HorizonTextLayer()
    let angleLayer = HorizonTextLayer()
    let dashLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       setUpLayers()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpLayers()
    }

    public override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            setUpLayers()
        }
    }
    // other stuff here ... 
}
```

Objective C++ calls to alloc view:

```
_horizonView = [[HorizonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 30)];
[bigView addSubview:_horizonView];
```

Objective C++ calls to delete view:

```
if ( _horizonView ) { [_horizonView removeFromSuperview]; [_horizonView release]; _horizonView = nil; }
```

I decided to encapsulate HorizonView by exposing only one public method. I don't know if is possible to declare a `protocol`, which is subclass of `UIView` (protocol isn't a class, is it?), so I came to class:

```
@objc
public class HorizonView: UIView {
    static func create(p1: CGPoint, andP2 p2: CGPoint) -> HorizonView {
        let implFrame = CGRect(x: p1.x, y: p1.y-10, width: p2.x-p1.x, height: 20)
        let impl = HorizonViewImpl(frame: implFrame)
        return impl
    }
}

private class HorizonViewImpl: HorizonView {

    var dashGap: (CGFloat, CGFloat)? = nil

    let titleLayer = HorizonTextLayer()
    let angleLayer = HorizonTextLayer()

    // old class code ...
}
```

Now Objective C++ alloc call looks so:

```
if ( _horizonView ) { [_horizonView removeFromSuperview]; [_horizonView release]; _horizonView = nil; }
_horizonView = [HorizonView createWithP1:CGPointMake(10, 10)
                                   andP2:CGPointMake(210,40)];
[EGLV addSubview:_horizonView];
```

And I constantly receive a crash, when profiling, seeing this:
[image]

Could you give some hints to detect the problem? 
Can such inheritance approach have some flaws?

Comment: Why is your Objective-C code doing explicit releases? Are you not using ARC?

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, I don't use ARC (there also is C++ code).

Comment: With your function `create(p1:p2:)` are you still trying to explicitly release  the object when you are finished with it? Because it is probably autoreleased given its name.

Comment: @JeremyP Oh, sorry, I forgot to say that view is released before. Updated the code sample.